# Low size pandas Dataframe expand when saved in csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, size

I have a pandas dataframe which I managed to downsize to 8GB (dropping columns and transforming many object column to .astype('category')). This is the output of .info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 61435992 entries, 0 to 64771731
Data columns (total 33 columns):
 #   Column           Dtype   
---  ------           -----   
 0   reftype          object  
 1   confscore        int8    
 2   paperid          int64   
 3   patent_string    object  
 4   uspto            int8    
 5   wherefound       category
 6   doi              object  
 7   pmid             float32 
 8   patent           int64   
 9   knowngood_dummy  int8    
 10  paperyear        float32 
 11  papertitle       object  
 12  magfieldid       float32 
 13  oecd_field       category
 14  oecd_subfield    category
 15  wosfield         category
 16  author           float32 
 17  entity_id        float32 
 18  affiliation2     float32 
 19  class            category
 20  foaf_name        object  
 21  type_entities    object  
 22  acronym          category
 23  pos#lat          float32 
 24  pos#long         float32 
 25  city_name        category
 26  city_lat         float32 
 27  city_lon         float32 
 28  state_name       category
 29  postcode         category
 30  country_name     category
 31  country_alpha3   category
 32  country_2        category
dtypes: category(12), float32(10), int64(2), int8(3), object(6)
memory usage: 7.6+ GB
```

I then used dak to export it in csv form in a single file as follows:

```
dask_db_emakg_prova.to_csv('df_emakg.csv', index=False, single_file=True) # this save to one file
```

However, when exported in csv form on my local computer its size increases to 22GB. How is this possible? Is there a way to export it at the size of the pandas df? I need to import it in tata and R o this is why I would like a csv file, but with 22GB it takes a lot to open.

Thank you

Comment: Instead of saving your df as csv, have you tried saving to the [feather](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_feather.html) format?

Comment: No I haven't but I am not sure that it will work on stata...